# How to configure Apache to completely ignore non configured hostnames AND serve configured hostnames?

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I am running Apache 2.4.29.

If I set a 000-default.conf like this and I enable it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    Redirect 404 /
    ErrorDocument 404 "Domain not configured on this server!!!!!!!!!"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then all the other virtual hosts in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory (that I enabled using a2ensite) return 404 as well. Everything is 404.

If I remove the 000-default-conf, or if I a2disite it, then any request from any domain will be accepted by Apache and it will be served by my other VirtualHost block in a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub.domain.com.conf` file that looks like this

```
<VirtualHost :*80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    # Some other stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

Any request made to the IP of my server, no matter the HostName in the header of the request will be treated and get a reply from that block. I would like that requests made to hostnames that aren't sub.domain.com receive a 404 response.

How to do that?

Comment: I'd start with removing the : after ServerName in sub.domain.com.conf and test again.

Comment: It's not here, I'm typing this by hand, I didn't copy paste it.

Comment: I edited it out from the question.

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently a problem with Docker not following symlinks from sites-enabled to sites-available because the two directories were on different volumes. I think this was the problem. I set both directory to point to the same volume and it seems to work now. I'm tired so I'm not sure, but I think this solved the problem.
Got the idea of using the same volume for both here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881904/docker-follow-symlink-outside-context/56492815#56492815
Well, apparently in the link above, he didn't do that, but that inspired me to do it